# Java TCP Socket on public

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, tcpsocket

I wrote a server and client Java TCP Socket, It works on private network(192.168.2.x) but how I have no idea how make it work with public ip. I think I should open a port in the router and use my server ip and this port to init client socket! I tried it and did not work.

Init of sockets here:

`Socket clientSocket = new Socket(IP, PORT);`

`ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);`

Answer (score 0):

- "Opening ports" is usually done on the firewall - and it should be done, if you are using one.
- In addition, you need your router to allow incoming traffic, this is usually done by port forwarding configuration / NAT section.
- Last but not least, you need the client on the external network to specify the external facing IP of your router, which is an IP address that is not in [the ranges reserved for private networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). 192.168.x.x is a range reserved for private networks and is not part of the public address space. it should be a different IP address.

You can find your router's public IP address by navigating http://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: - Sorry I translated it from my language, that's why I used "Opening ports", I think creating a socket with specified port, already open the port but I am not sure anyway.
- I did port forwarding but I don't know how to test it ? Can you suggest me a way of testing!
- I used my public ip and it did not work as I stated above.

Answer (score -1):

You should go to NAT section in your router and enable port forwarding, for example public ip:port will be 1.1.1.1:1 NATed to local 2.2.2.2:2, so you start your server on port 2 and connect with your client to 1.1.1.1 port 1.

Comment: I did it like [pic](http://i.imgur.com/dgEex16.png) . I did not work